# Install specific previous version of package using snap?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, kubernetes, snap

I would like to install `kubectl` version `1.2.4` on a machine. The Kubernetes documentation [recommends using `snap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-with-snap-on-ubuntu) for installation on Ubuntu.

`snap install --help` is not very useful, the one promising parameter `--revision=` doesn't work:

```
$ sudo snap install --revision=1.2.4 kubectl
error: cannot decode request body into snap instruction: invalid snap revision: "\"1.2.4\""
```

I suspect that `--revision` expects a SHA rather than a semver.

The `apt-get` convention of using `package=1.2.3` also doesn't work:

```
$ sudo snap install kubectl=1.2.4
error: snap "kubectl=1.2.4" not found
```

The [usage documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/core/usage) seems silent on the question.

Anybody know?

Answer (score 76):

1. you can run `snap info kubectl` which gives you a list of kubectl versions.
2. Then you can install your preferred version with --channel like this `sudo snap install kubectl --channel=1.6/stable --classic`
   or if you want to upgrade / downgrade to specific version:
   `sudo snap refresh kubectl --channel=1.6/stable --classic`

It seems that version 1.2.4 Is not available in snap, in that case you can download the executable `https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.2.4/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl`

Comment: why do we need `--classic`?

Comment: Same question as @lucidbrot - I often see the `--classic` flag but with no explanation as why that option would be used.

Comment: `--classic` means the snap is not built with specific permissions (i.e. strict mode), so adding `--classic` means it will run like a traditional binary with most permissions.

Comment: How do we prevent the snap from being updated after installing a specific version?

Comment: Preventing snap package upgrades: not impossible, but not elegant either (and for my team, this is a major shortcoming of `snap`):  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131182/how-can-i-disable-automatic-update-for-a-single-snap-in-ubuntu

Comment: I was able to install Ruby 3.0 dev version by `snap refresh ruby --channel=latest/edge` without the `sudo` but it asked for the password in a dialog window

Answer (score 1):

1. Run this

   ```
   snap refresh --edge sublime-text
   ```

   to update sublime text to the version you want or

   ```
   snap install --edge sublime-text
   ```

   to install sublime text.
2. The `--edge` represent the channel